# HTML5 - Hidding toolbar

Tags: iphone

Is there a way to hide this toolbar when somebody open my webpage on IPhone/Ipod touch?

[Valid XHTML http://tlab.in/toolbar.png](http://tlab.in/toolbar.png).

Regards

Comment: You mean! to hide the IPHONE toolbar! or this is a HTML toolbar that u have in your site?!

Comment: @Claudio: It's not possible. EDIT: turns out it's possible - amazing link @Arthur!

Answer (score 0):

Try this out! if you wanna fullscreen mode in your HTML page:(hidden Iphone`s toolbar)

http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1950-Detecting-iPhone-s-App-Mode-Full-Screen-Mode-For-Web-Applications.htm

**Important**:

keep in mind that this is possible if the guy add your page to the home screen! otherwise, is not possible to display it as fullscreen!

Comment: Thanks man, but i'm not looking for a way to do a webapp. I wonder if it is possible to show without this toolbar and if it is, how to do it.